Can we mask two words at the same time in attention mechanism?
I need to fine tune a language model and I want it to focus on particular words which will be looked up together. I want to mask them and the attention mechanism will run simoultaneously. The masked words will be defined by a syntactic parser. Is this possible? If yes please help me with technical details.
No I didnt. I m a computational linguist and I lack technical information.
